# How to improve PHP IP generator function

Tags: php, random, ip

I am trying to generate random public IP addresses using PHP. I would appreciate feedback on the function I have made to do this as below. Is there any aspects you think can be improved in how it's coded? Can it be done in less lines of code? Are there reserved numbers which I've not catered for? Should I be using mt_rand() instead of rand()? All feedback appreciated. Thanks.

```
function generateIP() {
    $q1 = rand(3,253);

    //stop the first quadrant being one from a resrved range
    while ($q1 == '10'|| $q1 == '100'|| $q1 == '127' || $q1 == '169' || $q1 == '172' || $q1 == '192' || $q1 == '198' || $q1 == '203' || $q1 == '224' || $q1 == '240') {
        $q1 = rand(3,253);
    }

    $q2 = rand(0,255);
    $q3 = rand(0,255);
    $q4 = rand(0,255);
    $ip = $q1.'.'.$q2.'.'.$q3.'.'.$q4;
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: why are you creating a ip generator?

Comment: Take a look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: I wonder why you are not creating the 1.0.0.0/8 and 2.0.0.0/8 networks, and why you are creating those networks formerly known as class D and E. They are still not being used, and never will. Additionally, the private networks are 10.0.0.0/8 (ok), 172.16.0.0/12 and 192.168.0.0/16 (you are excluding too much).

Comment: You could use `while (!in_array($q1, array(10, 100, 127, ...)))`

Comment: You need to know when to use Do While or While ... The main difference in a do while loop, ... Is that you execute your statement before looping ... You could safe energy

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```
function generateIP() {
$q1 = 0;
do
{
    $q1 = rand(1,255);

}
while($q1 != '0'|| $q1 != '10'|| $q1 != '100'|| $q1 != '127' || $q1 != '169' || $q1 != '172' || $q1 != '192' || $q1 != '198' || $q1 != '203' || $q1 != '224' || $q1 != '240'){

    $q2 = rand(0,255);
    $q3 = rand(0,255);
    $q4 = rand(0,255);
    $ip = $q1.'.'.$q2.'.'.$q3.'.'.$q4;
    return $ip;
};
```

Comment: Missing a ; at the end of the while statment but otherwise looking good :)

Comment: How can it be working properly (apart missing semicolon), if you don't allow `$q1` to be anything except invalid values (not totally invalid, but invalid in this particular case).

Comment: i type it quickly out of my mind when i saw this question, didn't test it @ that moment, just wanted to demostrate the do while
fixed the 2 issues.

Comment: This is clearly broken in multiple ways; it isn't syntactically valid as it stands and even if you fix the syntax the condition in the `while()` statement is always true.

Answer (score -1):

Generate IP in RANGE

```
public static function generateRandomIp($start, $end) {
    if (strcmp($start, $end) > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $arrStart = explode('.',$start);
    $arrEnd = explode('.', $end);

    // First
    $arrIp[0] = rand($arrStart[0], $arrEnd[0]);

    // Second
    if ($arrIp[0] == $arrStart[0] && $arrIp[0] == $arrEnd[0]) {
        $arrIp[1] = rand($arrStart[1], $arrEnd[1]);
    } elseif ($arrIp[0] == $arrStart[0]) {
        $arrIp[1] = rand($arrStart[1], 255);
    } elseif ($arrIp[0] == $arrEnd[0]) {
        $arrIp[1] = rand(0, $arrEnd[1]);
    } else {
        $arrIp[1] = rand(0, 255);
    }

    // Third
    if ($arrIp[1] == $arrStart[1] && $arrIp[1] == $arrEnd[1]) {
        $arrIp[2] = rand($arrStart[2], $arrEnd[2]);
    } elseif ($arrIp[1] == $arrStart[1]) {
        $arrIp[2] = rand($arrStart[2], 255);
    } elseif ($arrIp[1] == $arrEnd[1]) {
        $arrIp[2] = rand(0, $arrEnd[2]);
    } else {
        $arrIp[2] = rand(0, 255);
    }

    // Fourth
    if ($arrIp[2] == $arrStart[2] && $arrIp[02] == $arrEnd[2]) {
        $arrIp[3] = rand($arrStart[3], $arrEnd[3]);
    } elseif ($arrIp[2] == $arrStart[2]) {
        $arrIp[3] = rand($arrStart[3], 255);
    } elseif ($arrIp[2] == $arrEnd[2]) {
        $arrIp[3] = rand(0, $arrEnd[3]);
    } else {
        $arrIp[3] = rand(0, 255);
    }

    return implode(".", $arrIp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sprintf("%s.%s.%s.%s",
    rand(0,255),
    rand(0,255),
    rand(0,255),
    rand(0,255)         
);
```